# Allow the user to hit the menu once every day in Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, datetime, actionbarsherlock

I'm creating a program that has a menu item in actionbarsherlock. Now I want the user to click that menu once a day and no more. How can I accomplish this? Here's what I have so far:

```
int hour = today.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

if (hour < 24) {

    try {
        if (gotGenders.contentEquals("Male")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Monitor.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle(gotNames);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You are currently burning "
                    + caloriesForMen() + " calories per hour");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Discard",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            showAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
            showAlertDialog.show();
        }
        else if (gotGenders.contentEquals("Female")) {
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Monitor.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle(gotNames);
            alertDialog.setMessage("You are currently burning "
                    + caloriesForWomen() + " calories per hour");
            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Save",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            // dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Discard",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });

            alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
            showAlertDialog = alertDialog.create();
            showAlertDialog.show();

            count = 1;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        AlertDialog.Builder errorDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                Monitor.this);
        errorDialog.setTitle("No User Selected!");
        // errorDialog.setMessage("You are currently burning " +
        // caloriesForWomen() + " per hour");
        errorDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

        errorDialog.setCancelable(false);
        errorAlertDialog = errorDialog.create();
        errorAlertDialog.show();
    }
} else {
    count = 0;

    AlertDialog.Builder waitDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Monitor.this);
    waitDialog.setTitle("Wait after the day is over");
    waitDialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

    waitDialog.setCancelable(false);
    waitAlertDialog = waitDialog.create();
    waitAlertDialog.show();
}
```

This allows me to select the menu more than once, how can I limit it to only one click a day? Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong... But no matter how you implement this, a client side-only implementation will ALWAYS be bypassable by simply changing the system time in the device's settings... Just pointing that out so you know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To realize this you should stock the last visited date somewhere (db, sharedpreferences, in a file), then:

```
long lastVistedDateTime = getLastVistedDateTime();
int lastDay = new Date(lastVistedDateTime).getDay();
int today = Calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
if (today != lastDay){
    //an other day
    setLastVistedDateTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}
```

To compare dates with the current Locale, use:

```
String lastDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(new Date(lastVistedDateTime));
String nowDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(new Date());
if (!nowDate.equals(lastDate)){
    //an other day
    setLastVistedDateTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
}
```

Comment: So this code                `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                time = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);` gives me the hour from the device. I put this in my onCreate method. So is `time` what I would put in here `String lastDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM).format(new Date(lastVistedDateTime));`?

Answer (score 2):

I think that in general gezdy's answer has the right approach, but I'd like to propose a simplification.

Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR

gives you the current day of the year (1-365). So, rather than doing any math with milliseconds, just grab that value and store it, and compare it on subsequent attempts. Should reduce the code in gezdy's answer to about 3 lines (while doing the exact same thing).

The only possible drawbacks are

1. User can alter the clock on their device
2. User might experience an unintended prevention of app use if they only use the app once a
   year and then come back on the same exact day of year a year later.
   (highly unlikely).